# Creating a "box-webpage" upon click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to accomplish something that might be relatively simple, but I don't know what I would call it (if there is a specific name for it), hence my searches have proved useless.

What I'm trying to accomplish is simple: I have a page built off off the Masonry jquery plugin (similar to http://designshack.net/tutorialexamples/masonry/demos/masonry.html). All I want to do is that when I click on a specific picture, it creates a "box" that fills up part of the screen and can contain another webpage (to describe the picture) while fading out most of the background. Then when I click outside of the box, it returns to all of my pictures.

I've seen this before, as I'm sure everybody else has, but for the life of me I cannot remember an example to look at or how best to do this. I don't have too much experience with javascript or jquery (which is why I'm asking this), but any help to point me in the right direction, whether it *is* using javascript or html/css, would be great.

If anybody does get the gist of what I'm describing and can explain it better, then you're more than welcome to edit..

Comment: Are you trying to describe a "lightbox"? http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

Comment: Usually, that box is just a <div/> element having html markup inside, which hides and shows using display property. Depends how you want, you can have just one box for all the images, and when you click on a picture you dynamically update the content of the box (probably with AJAX), or you can have a box for each image, with the content already there, and you just have to show/hide it.

Comment: Thanks @Strelok. Exactly what I was looking for. I knew somebody would have a clean solution.

Answer (score 0):

What you need are modal windows.

I know the twitter bootstrap has built a pretty good framework for this:

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

If you aren't using the bootstrap directly you might be able to pick out what you need.